# Can't remove directory/file from external hard drive

Tags: virtualbox, hard-drive, filesystem, windows-10, 22.04

I have an external hard drive (exFAT) with an old backed up Apple Photos library, but I can't delete the folder. Navigating into the folder structure in Windows I dead-end here:

```
Photos Library.photoslibrary\private\com.apple.cloudphotosd\CloudSync.noindex\Engine\filecache\
```

Inside the filecache folder is a file/directory called `AUx`, which seems to be the one causing issues. Windows thinks it's a directory but I can't open it, when I try to it gives me a permission error, but I also don't get options to change permissions when right clicking on the folder. I tried mounting the external hard drive to an Ubuntu virtual machine in virtualbox and tried to remove the file/folder there but I get the following:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 May  1  2019 AUx

$ sudo rm AUx/
rm: cannot remove 'AUx/': Is a directory

$ sudo rmdir AUx/
rmdir: failed to remove 'AUx/': Not a directory
```

So it's a directory but it's also not a directory? What gives? I also tried using the -rf flags with `rm` and it doesn't give me an error but `AUx` is still there.

My final recourse is to backup the entire external and just reformat, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

**Edit:** I realized that "aux" is a reserved word in Windows, I wonder if this has anything to do with the issue? I wish I had a Mac I could plug my hard drive into to see if I could delete it that way.

Comment: do you want to delete `Library.photoslibrary` and all below it?

Comment: Yes I want to delete that folder and everything below it. I have tried using the `-r` (recursive) flag and the `-f` (force) flag with `rm` but nothing happens, regardless of if I try to delete from `Photos Library.photoslibrary` or the `AUx` file/folder itself.

Comment: I would try a live usb with linux, to exclude any impact of Windows